# PyInstaller / auto-py-to-exe missing core python39.dll files

Tags: python

- I am working on a project in PyCharm on Windows 10 using Python
  3.9.0.
- Every time I attempt to compile it from the PyCharm command line to
  EXE it yields.

Error:

```
OSError: Python library not found: libpython39m.dll, libpython3.9.dll, libpython3.9m.dll, libpython39.dll, python39.dll
```

I have attempted to reinstall Python and the compiler program.
How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you install pyinstaller and upgrade `pip` too:

`pip install pyinstaller` and `pip install --upgrade pip`

When I had these errors the above commands helped.

If that doesn't help try installing Python 3.9.1

Comment: Just attempted it. pip is using the latest available version, and reinstalling PyInstaller did nothing. Also tried 3.9.1 Python, no effect

Comment: Have you set your python ```PATH``` in the [environment variables](https://www.pythoncentral.io/add-python-to-path-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/)? If not try setting it in there. You can completely uninstall python and reinstall it again. Also you can try running ```pyinstaller``` from command prompt/shell to see if the error is still there.

Comment: Tried all of them, nope.

Comment: Ok let's continue then - how do you install python - from Micosoft Store or from the official site? The store version has problems like yours. Try compiling your program with `pyinstaller -F yourptogram.py`

Comment: I download the executable installer from the official site.